# SEO For Banner Images

Tags: seo

I'm working on a site with large banners on the home page under the main menu that rotate. I'm being told that for SEO I need to overlay the text in the banner over the banner image and remove the text from the image itself. Isn't that what alt tags are for or am I ignorant? Is there anything to be gained by this approach? Seems like wasted effort to me.

My apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`alt` tags are perfectly fine for providing a text description of what is visible in your banners.  The only advantage of having real text on the image is that you may be better able to provide localized banners.

Answer (score 1):

Adding text as overlays to image rather than having embedding on image version is a better approach because:

1. You can add content per your needs (with efficient usage of Keywords) and thus control keyword density on a particular page. SEO benefit.
2. Tomorrow if you need to update the text on image; generating new images (with updated text) would be a costly and may need a designer requirement to regenerate image. Where as changing overlay text is quite simple process and takes no time.
3. Text & Image can be updated independently.